Firefox extension that lets you lasso links and open them all or copy their links to the clipboard like Snap Links
Snap Links / Snap Links Plus has an annoying bug; it sometimes goes crazy and randomly starts lassoing (possibly because it doesn't correctly register the right-mousebutton-up state).
The latest is 3.1.11, I've also tried the older versions listed here, same problem.
Linkclump appears to be Chrome only
Multi Links Plus is so old it doesn't work with the latest Firefox ("This addon could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt").

please describe in more detail what the extension needs to do

@Bindestrich When holding down the right-mouse button you can draw a rectangle and open all links inside that rectangle as tabs. https://i.imgur.com/LmDnBox.png

Linkclump for Firefox

Firefox port of the equally named extension for Chrome.

Not up to date as Linkclump for Chrome. The latest version is from 2022. Snap Links Plus (2021).


Thank you sir! I guess the Google gods were not with me.
